Axios Network Error in React Native project - how to handle this issue?
At first I started to develop my mobile app using Expo, but then migrated the components (and generally the whole UI) to plain React Native (react-native). No matter what I am trying to do (e.g login, checkAuth, get some resources from my API etc.) I got the Axios Network Error. This problem occured after migrating to RN. When I was working with Expo there were no problems with API requests handling.

My API is deployed and secured (HTTPS)
NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is set in Info.plist
The same requests are handled properly in postman
Tried doing the same requests using FetchAPI - the same error

This is my network related part of the Info.plist file:
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

This is my Axios config (also tried without this data value set):
import axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://myurl.pl/api/v1',
  data: undefined,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

export default axiosInstance;

This is my context which is responsible for these failed requests:
import React, {createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import axiosInstance from '@/utils/axiosConfig';
import axios from 'axios';
import {jwtDecode} from 'jwt-decode';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

interface AuthContextProps {
  user: any;
  loading: boolean;
  login: (username: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
  logout: () => void;
  checkAuth: () => void;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextProps | undefined>(undefined);

const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadUser = async () => {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');
      if (token) {
        axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common[
          'Authorization'
        ] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        setUser(jwtDecode(token));
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };

    loadUser();
  }, []);

  const login = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.post('/auth/login/', {
        username,
        password,
      });

      const token = response.data.access;

      await AsyncStorage.setItem('access', token);
      axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common[
        'Authorization'
      ] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      setUser(jwtDecode(token));
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
        console.log('Axios error:', error.message);
        if (error.response) {
          console.log('Response error:', error.response.data);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Unexpected error:', error);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('access');
    delete axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
    setUser(null);
    navigation.navigate('login');
  };

  const checkAuth = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');
      if (token) {
        axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common[
          'Authorization'
        ] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        await axiosInstance.post('/auth/verify/');
        setUser(jwtDecode(token));
      } else {
        throw new Error('No token');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setUser(null);
      console.error('Authentication check failed', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, loading, login, logout, checkAuth}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider');
  }
  return context;
};

export {AuthProvider, useAuth};

Has anyone came up with a clear solution for this issue? I've seen that many people encountered this issue but the solution they've provided are meaningless in my case :(
